# S Browser Bookmarks URI

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, bookmarks, android-browser, contentobserver

For the native browser I get the Bookmarks URI like this:

```
Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI;
```

And for chrome it's like:

```
Uri.parse("content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks");
```

What about Samsung S Browser?

Answer (score 1):

This is the URI for the Samsung S-Browser bookmarks table.

```
content://com.sec.android.app.sbrowser.browser/bookmarks
```